# How to add missing dependencies to a useEffect hook that is run only once?

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'myDate' and 'setMyDate'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.

How can missing dependencies be added to a `useEffect` that is run only once? The following example generates the warning above:

```
const [ myDate, setMyDate ] = useState(0)

const spinner = useRef(null)
useEffect( () => {
    spinner.current = setInterval( () => {
        d = Date.now()
        if (d < myDate)
            setUpdate(d)
    }, 997 )
}, [])
```

If I include them, I create an infinite loop, as the `setTimeout` changes the values of the dependencies:

```
const spinner = useRef(null)
useEffect( () => {
    spinner.current = setInterval( () => {
        d = Date.now()
        if (d < myDate)
            setMyDate(d)
    }, 997 )
}, [myDate, setMyDate])
```

If I remove the dependency array, the `useEffect` runs on each render, and sets up an infinite number of setIntervals:

```
const spinner = useRef(null)
useEffect( () => {
    spinner.current = setInterval( () => {
        d = Date.now()
        if (d < myDate)
            setMyDate(d)
    }, 997 )
})
```

I also tried removing the `useEffect` entirely, thinking that since `spinner` is a `useRef`, it would not reassign on each component render... but no:

```
const spinner = useRef(null)
spinner.current = setInterval( () => {
    d = Date.now()
    if (d < myDate)
        setMyDate(d)
}
```

Also tried using a functional update approach, like so, but lint error persist and the code doesn't work:

```
const spinner = useRef(null)
useEffect( () => {
    spinner.current = setInterval( () => {
        d = Date.now()
        setMyDate(d => {
            if (d < myDate)
                setMyDate(d)
        }
    }, 997 )
}, [setMyDate])
```

I'm stuck... caught between a rock and a hard place! How can I resolve this lint warning?

Comment: I don't know if it will work because sometime I have weird infinite loop because a method doesn't change. What you can do is create a method that set the interval and call this method in the use effect by assigning it as a dependency. Normally it wil work because like I said, method does'nt change.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @Galupuf Create a ``setInterval`` once, which calls a hook update every _n_ seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to get `myDate` (named `date` in my code just to be clear) from the `setMyDate` function itself instead of passing it as a dependency.

`setMyDate` is memoized and therefore doesn't need to be passed as a dependency.

```js
const [myDate, setMyDate] = useState(0);
const spinner = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  spinner.current = setInterval(() => {
    const d = Date.now();

    setMyDate(date => {
      if (d < date) {
        return d;
      }
      return date;
    });
  }, 997);
}, []);
```

Comment: Nice... the functional update approach. In my case, ``myDate`` and ``setMyDate``are ``useContext`` hooks, and so the linter is still complaining about ``setMyDate``

Comment: @kmiklas That does make a difference, you should have explained that in your question. Please edit your post and add the code of the hook in question.

Comment: Valentin thx willdo. I was going for a minimal example.

Answer (score 2):

what seems to work for me is to separate the logic of the interval into a `useCallback()` hook with no dependencies. This memoizes the function and makes sure that the function is only built on initial component render.

Then, inside of the effect you call the function you built with `useCallback()`, and provide that to the effect dependencies array. Then the effect will rebuild only if the `useCallback()` function changes – which it won't because it has no dependencies.

Should remove the linter warnings from `react-hooks`

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback} from 'react'

export default function IntervalHook() {

  const [ myDate, setMyDate ] = useState(0)
  const spinner = useRef(0)

  const spinnerFn = useCallback(() => {
    spinner.current = setInterval(() => {
      const d = Date.now()
      setMyDate(d)
    }, 997 )
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    spinnerFn()     
    return () => {  // this return statement clears the interval when the component unmounts
      if (spinner.current) {
        clearInterval(spinner.current)
        spinner.current = 0
      }
    }
  }, [spinnerFn])

  return (
    <span>{myDate}</span>
  )
}
```